# Get image to toggle for active state in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using a bootstrap 3 template, I'm trying to get an image to toggle between open and closed states when a dropdown is open.

So far I can get the image to toggle when clicked, but then when the dropdown link is no longer active it does not untoggle.

HTML

```
<a id="menu-toggle2" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<img id="icon-switch2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Follow Us">
```

CSS

```
$('#menu-toggle2').on({
    'click': function(){
        $('#icon-switch2').attr('src','http://placehold.it/351x151');
    }
});
```

fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/k237t19r/

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in a few ways. Firstly, you could track the active state, and switch the image based on that.

```
var active = false:   

$('#menu-toggle2').on({
        'click': function(){
    If (!active){
            $('#icon-switch2').attr('src','http://placehold.it/351x151');
}else {
 $('#icon-switch2').attr('src','http://placehold2.it/351x151');
}
        }
    });
```

Or, you could use classes with background images;

```
//css

#icon-switch2 {background-image: url ('path-to-image):}

#icon-switch2.active {background-image: url }

//jquery

$('#menu-toggle2').on({
        'click': function(){
            $('#icon-switch2').toggleClass('active');

}

    }):
```

I apologise for the formatting, horrible on mobile.